# Iteration of HashMap and ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap, iteration

I am having hashmap and Arraylist.

*Hashmap*

```
Map<Integer, List<String>> mMap = new HashMap<Integer, List<String>>();
```

Here Key (Interger) will be the index position of one element in the anotherlsit and value will be the list.

*Arraylist*

```
List<testBean> mList= new ArrayList<testBean>();
```

Now I want to iterate the arraylist and compare the indexposition of element in the ArrayList with the key value of Map.If it matched I will go for another logic.I got struck here on how to iterate simultaneously and compare .Please help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just iterate through the list and use map get:

```
for(int i = 0;i < mList.size();i++) {
    List<String> list = mMap.get(i);
    if (list == null) {
        // index was a key in map
    } else {
        // index was not a key in map
    }
}
```

Strictly speaking this is not 100% correct if you have a key in map that maps to a null value. In that case you can check for key presence with `mMap.containsKey()` method.

Comment: Hi,Thank you so much.I have another doubt here.If the key value mathced in the index position of list then I have to get the the corresponding list for the key in Map Since Map contains key as indexposition and value is the List.Can you please guide me?

Comment: The list in the second row or the code sample is the list for that index position. I don't exactly understand the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int i = 0;i < mList.size();i++) {
    if(mMap.containsKey(mList.get(i)) {
        // Put your logic here
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Eidan ,Thank you so much.I have another doubt here.If the key value mathced in the index position of list then I have to get the the corresponding list for the key in Map Since Map contains key as indexposition and value is the List.Can you please guide me

Comment: I don't entirely understand your comment. Did you mean you want the string list at the given index? mMap.get(mList.get(i)) ?

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically you can do this using iterator:

```
Iterator<TheBean> itb = mList.iterator();
Iterator<Entry<Integer, List<String>>> itmap = mMap.iterator();
while (itb.hasNext() && itmap.hasNext()) {
    TheBean b = itb.next();
    Entry<Integer, List<String>> e = itmap.next();

    // do you logic that I IMHO do not understand exactly.
}
```

However this will not work because map does not preserve order of keys. So, if I understand that index of list should match key of map you can do the following:

```
for (int i = 0; i < mList.size(); i++) {
   TheBean b = mList.get(i);
   List<String> listOfStrings = mMap.get(i);
   if (listOfStrings != null) {
        // implement your logic here.
   }
}
```

I hope this helps

Comment: I am really sorry, but your explanation sounds too complicated. However if you can give some real life example it can help. Moreover it probably can help us to suggest you better data structure that looks for me .... strange.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this logic

```
 for (Integer mapKey : mMap.keySet()) {
        //iterate through list
        for (String listIndex : mMap.get(mapKey)) {
            //compare the map key value with list value
            if(listIndex != null && mapKey == Integer.valueOf(listIndex)){
                //write your logic here
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi Durga , I want to iterate the arraylist also.